# Fun and engaging ways to record a float

Tags: jquery, slider, range

Ok, I am working on a jquery powered website and one of the things I need to do is allow users to record a float from 0-10, but a reasonably lightweight solution.

I have considered using a range slider but the browser compatibility really isn't that great. Are there any interesting jquery solutions that people are aware of that could be used as an alternative to a range slider?

Comment: How is compatibility not great for a range slider? You can make one of those work in IE6 with enough effort… in which case, if you’d like to turn this into a “fun and engaging” question, you should possibly ask on [ux.se]. (I’m not sure whether it’s considered constructive there, though.)

Comment: How about typing it in? If there's one thing I hate it's sliders with imprecise control over the value to be selected. (For example Windows sound mixer.)

Comment: I just don't really trust things where you have to work back compatibility. I think typing it in isn't a really engaging way of doing things. Maybe if I used more CSS on it it could be engaging enough I don't know though hmm

Comment: Why would being backwards-compatible make something less engaging? You can be backwards-compatible without having the exact same thing on every browser ever.